# alphabetical order - return index of row

Tags: jquery

I got a table which is ordered by one of the td columns.. When a new row is inserted I need to get the index where the new row will fit without the alphabetical order is corrupted..

I got a method here, but it only works with numbers.. How can you make it work with strings too?

```
this.get_row_index = function(value, td_index){
    var index = 0;
    td_index = td_index ? td_index:0;
    $('tr', this.scope.tbl_list).each(function(){
        if(parseInt($('td', this).eq(td_index).html()) > value){
            return false;
        }
        index++;
    });

    return index;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript strings can just be compared with `>` and `<`.  So, removing the `parseInt` should do it.

Comment: True, I would also use `.text()` instead of `.html()` to avoid comparing the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is the first column you're sorting by, I found this works:

```
function sortAlpha(a,b){
    return a.innerHTML > b.innerHTML ? 1 : -1;
};

$(function() {
    $('table#thisOne tr').sort(sortAlpha).appendTo('table#thisOne');
});
```

..to sort this table:

```
<table id="thisOne">
    <tr><td>Zebra</td><td>0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Bees</td><td>11</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Apples</td><td>101</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Carrots</td><td>19</td></tr>
</table>
```